# Deleting temp files from server on session end

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-asax

In my app I modify an image based on the users selected options.  Each time I modify the default image I save and name it as user's ID & `date.now.tostring("yyyyMMddHHmmssf")` to fix my problem with browser caching.  This works fine, but now I could potentially end up with a lot of old images hanging around.

Now how can I delete all the images from my `~/Images/Temp/userID` folder on the server?  I was thinking about using the `Session_End` or `Application_end` subs in `Global.asax`, but I don't think I can access any of my variables to get the path for the temp images.

How can I delete these temp files after session end or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session End only fires for in-process sessions and it's not guaranteed (e.g. the server could lose power and it wouldn't fire). Application End shouldn't be firing that often and (as you pointed out) you probably wouldn't have the data you needed to perform the cleanup.

It's not *bad* to perform cleanup work when a session ends, but for this particular problem there may be a better, more deterministic solution.

If unique naming is the source of the problem, several options come to mind:

- Use a naming convention which allows you to run a Windows task periodically to identify old images and clean them up. Powershell is pretty flexible for tasks like this.
- Serve the images with a varying query string parameter at the end of the name to avoid caching (but keep the file name consistent).

  Example: `<img src="images/tim-medora.jpg?v=123" alt="picture" />`
- Serve the images dynamically through a handler. This lets you control cache settings, vary the query string, etc.
- Give the images a custom extension and set different cache settings for that extension in IIS. A web browser will have no problem with an image tag that points to a custom extension as long as its a valid image.

Comment: Query string parameter is the easiest...basically, just have one name for the file and overwrite it whenever it is updated. Then when you set the source of your image(s) (in your code behind, if you want), append a query string to the image name. It can be any random value...its purpose is to trick the web browser into downloading the image again, thus ensuring that you will never see an old, cached version of the image.

Comment: This is like 4 answers-in-one...  1)I was trying to avoid having another program or task clean up old file.  2,3,4)I'll have to read up on how to use these suggestions since I'm still new to web development. I'm doing just about everything trough code behind in VS2010 if that makes difference.  This probably isn't the correct way to do things, but I'm more of a Windows .NET programmer than a ASP/web developer.

Comment: The query string did the trick.  Now, each user (<200) will only create one temp image.  I found a perfect question at http://forums.asp.net/t/1561843.aspx/1 where the OP is doing almost exactly what I'm doing except he's saving the modified image to the handler's response output stream.  If I can do that then I wouldn't need to save these silly images in the first place.  Now I just need to figure out how to use the handler....